# awk + print the field from line that defined with double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

how to print the third field from line that defined with double quotes

for example

```
echo activate.bash /home/adm/run.sh "run on machine with eth2 active" "94061" | awk '{print $3}'
```

I expected that the awk will print the third filed in the  double quotes

```
 run on machine with eth2 active
```

but its print

```
 run
```

so what’s I need to fix in my ksh syntax?

other example

```
echo 123 123 "1 2 3 4 5" | awk '{print $3}'
```

should print

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I see no awk script. What's activate.bash? What's run.sh?

Comment: I only want to print the third filed , see please update quastion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom field separator in awk like this:

```
s='activate.bash /home/adm/run.sh "run on machine with eth2 active" "94061"'
echo "$s" | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
run on machine with eth2 active
```

**PS:** Better to use:

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
```

#### [Working Code Demo](http://ideone.com/CgnqPk)

Comment: @maihabunash: Check linked demo, both of your expected output are showing in the examples.

Comment: I not want to set the line in s parameter !

Comment: this line not print any output --> echo  activate.bash /home/adm/run.sh "run on machine with eth2 active" "94061" | awk -F '"' '{print $3}'

Comment: check demo link again, you are not quoting `echo` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the following example:

```
 cat numbers
 123 123 "run on machine with eth2 active" "94061"


cat numbers | awk -F '"' 'BEGIN{OFS=" ";} {print $2;}'
```

OUTPUT:    run on machine with eth2 active

Comment: This answer is nothing but a copy of my answer below with many problems like useless use of `cat` and redundant use of `BEGIN{OFS=" ";}`.